# How to remove the extra key from python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to remove extra key from my output but not sure how to remove.

**Extra Key**
`('DiskStatus', {'DiskStatus':[`

**Expected Key**
`('DiskStatus': [`

**test.csv**

```
test.csv
/,9.8G,6.8G,27%
/home,4.8G,3.6G,22%
/opt,9.8G,5.2G,44%
/tmp,3.9G,3.6G,2%
```

**Code**

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
import collections
import socket
type = 'STATUS'
hostname =  socket.gethostname()
hotst = {}.fromkeys(['ServerName'],hostname)
type = {}.fromkeys(['type'],type)
disk_status = {'DiskStatus': []}
header = ['Mount', 'Total', 'available', 'used']
with open('test.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for line in reader:
        #updated line
        disk_status["DiskStatus"].append(collections.OrderedDict(zip(header, line)))

status = dict(hotst.items() + type.items())
order = collections.OrderedDict(status)
new_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
new_dict["ServerName"]=status["ServerName"]
new_dict["type"]=status["type"]
new_dict["DiskStatus"]=disk_status
print new_dict
```

**Code Output**

```
OrderedDict([('ServerName', 'dlccwsdigdsu03'), ('type', 'STATUS'), ('DiskStatus', {'DiskStatus': [OrderedDict([('Mount', '/'), ('Total', '9.8G'), ('available', '6.8G'), ('used', '27%')]), OrderedDict([('Mount', '/home'), ('Total', '4.8G'), ('available', '3.6G'), ('used', '22%')]), OrderedDict([('Mount', '/opt'), ('Total', '9.8G'), ('available', '5.2G'), ('used', '44%')]), OrderedDict([('Mount', '/tmp'), ('Total', '3.9G'), ('available', '3.6G'), ('used', '2%')])]})])
```

**Expected Output**

```
OrderedDict([('ServerName', 'dlccwsdigdsu03'), ('type', 'STATUS'), ('DiskStatus': [OrderedDict([('Mount', '/'), ('Total', '9.8G'), ('available', '6.8G'), ('used', '27%')]), OrderedDict([('Mount', '/home'), ('Total', '4.8G'), ('available', '3.6G'), ('used', '22%')]), OrderedDict([('Mount', '/opt'), ('Total', '9.8G'), ('available', '5.2G'), ('used', '44%')]), OrderedDict([('Mount', '/tmp'), ('Total', '3.9G'), ('available', '3.6G'), ('used', '2%')])]})])
```

Comment: Your expected output is invalid Python literal: A `dict` must be enclosed with braces, not parentheses. Maybe you want `('DiskStatus`, [...])` (note the comma vs colon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you wanted `('DiskStatus', [...])` instead of `('DiskStatus': [...])` (comma vs. colon, the latter of which is invalid syntax in Python), you could just take the value out of the original dictionary:

```
new_dict["DiskStatus"] = disk_status["DiskStatus"]
```